# Getting response from AWS | Appsync

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I've Successfully Integrated the [AWS-Client-App](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/building-a-client-app-ios.html) Sample couple of days ago then i started something from scratch. Let me give you my project specificaitons:-

```
Xcode version : Version 9.4 (9F1027a)
Language : Swift 4.0
Database : DynamoDB
And Using AppSync for syncing database
```

I Have a schema

```
type Mutation {
    #------ User ------#
    CreateUser(
        FirstName: String,
        Username: String,
        Password: String,
        CreatedOn: Int
    ): User
    UpdateUser(UserId: ID!, FirstName: String!, Username: String!): User
    DeleteUser(UserId: ID!): User
}

type Query {
    ####------ User ------#
    GetUser(UserId: ID!): User
    CheckUsername(Username: String): [User]
    CheckPhoneNumber(Phone: String): [User]
    #------ Login ------#
    CheckUserLogin(Username: String, Password: String): [User]
}

type User {
    UserId: ID!
    FirstName: String
    Username: String
    #Password: String
    Bio: String
    Phone: String
    Email: String
    Address: String
    WebsiteUrl: String
    ProfilePicture: String
    CreatedOn: Int
    Updated: Int
    Status: Boolean
    LastLoggedIn: Int
    IpAddress: String
}

schema {
    query: Query
    mutation: Mutation
}
```

A simple query in .graphql file

```
query CheckUsername($Username:String){
  CheckUsername(Username:$Username)
  {
      Username
  }
}
```

and generated a file called check Queries.swift

```
import AWSAppSync

public final class CheckUsernameQuery: GraphQLQuery {
  public static let operationString =
    "query CheckUsername($Username: String) {\n  CheckUsername(Username: $Username) {\n    __typename\n    Username\n  }\n}"

  public var Username: String?

  public init(Username: String? = nil) {
    self.Username = Username
  }

  public var variables: GraphQLMap? {
    return ["Username": Username]
  }

  public struct Data: GraphQLSelectionSet {
    public static let possibleTypes = ["Query"]

    public static let selections: [GraphQLSelection] = [
      GraphQLField("CheckUsername", arguments: ["Username": GraphQLVariable("Username")], type: .list(.object(CheckUsername.selections))),
    ]

    public var snapshot: Snapshot

    public init(snapshot: Snapshot) {
      self.snapshot = snapshot
    }

    public init(checkUsername: [CheckUsername?]? = nil) {
      self.init(snapshot: ["__typename": "Query", "CheckUsername": checkUsername.flatMap { $0.map { $0.flatMap { $0.snapshot } } }])
    }

    public var checkUsername: [CheckUsername?]? {
      get {
        return (snapshot["CheckUsername"] as? [Snapshot?]).flatMap { $0.map { $0.flatMap { CheckUsername(snapshot: $0) } } }
      }
      set {
        snapshot.updateValue(newValue.flatMap { $0.map { $0.flatMap { $0.snapshot } } }, forKey: "CheckUsername")
      }
    }

    public struct CheckUsername: GraphQLSelectionSet {
      public static let possibleTypes = ["User"]

      public static let selections: [GraphQLSelection] = [
        GraphQLField("__typename", type: .nonNull(.scalar(String.self))),
        GraphQLField("Username", type: .scalar(String.self)),
      ]

      public var snapshot: Snapshot

      public init(snapshot: Snapshot) {
        self.snapshot = snapshot
      }

      public init(username: String? = nil) {
        self.init(snapshot: ["__typename": "User", "Username": username])
      }

      public var __typename: String {
        get {
          return snapshot["__typename"]! as! String
        }
        set {
          snapshot.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "__typename")
        }
      }

      public var username: String? {
        get {
          return snapshot["Username"] as? String
        }
        set {
          snapshot.updateValue(newValue, forKey: "Username")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then i called this block of code to run the query

```
let query = CheckUsernameQuery(Username:"testuser1")
AppSyncManager.Client().fetch(query: query, cachePolicy: .fetchIgnoringCacheData) {
    (result, error) in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
        return
    }
    let username = result?.data?.checkUsername![0]?.username
}
```

And I'm Getting the following response

```
▿ Optional<GraphQLResult<Data>>
  ▿ some : GraphQLResult<Data>
    - data : nil
    - errors : nil
    - source : AWSAppSync.GraphQLResult<AppName.CheckUsernameQuery.Data>.Source.server
    - dependentKeys : nil
```

The query works well when i test it in Appsync Api panel but not working in the app. No Error, No Data nothing at all? What am i possibly doing wrong if any of you have an idea just feel free to let me know, it would be a great help for me. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the same input on the console? i.e. "testuser1"? 

`data: nil and errors: nil` indicate that the execution was successfully but there was nothing to return. Are you getting data back in the console?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. i don't think the problem is caused by the input, i have a "testuser1" in the database the query work in the query panel of appsync. what i think the from is from the app end @RohanDubal